# changing engine type to MyISAM unknown engine

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

i need to change table type from innoDB to myISAM

ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE = MyISAM;

Tried this but results in error:

Error 1286: Unknown storage engine 'MEMORY' SQL Statement: ALTER TABLE `tab_name`  ENGINE = MyISAM

I was able to do the same a few months ago   but unable to do now.

Can anyone help?

thanks

Comment: In order to change the engine type MySQL will have to make a temporary copy in memory. Has your MySQL installation been changed? Apparently, if it worked in the past, and doesn't now, the engine MEMORY isn't available. A work around would be to export the table using phpMyAdmin with all data, edit the SQL file to change the engine, and then import it.

Comment: What version of MySQL or MariaDB?

Answer (score 3):

Do you have myisam enabled in your install? Check with

```
show engines;
```

Comment: You can't not have MyISAM enabled. It's required for the system tables in the mysql schema (at least prior to MySQL 8.0). But it's a good tip to use `show engines` to check for the MEMORY storage engine.

Comment: My understanding was that it could be turned off for mariadb which this was also tagged.

Comment: Yes our cloud provider doesn;t allow myISAM anymore :( thanks !